# Is it Asur to wear apparel with the Versace symbol on it?

Tags: halacha, clothing, avodah-zarah, symbols-symbology

The [Versace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Versace) symbol is a Medusa which stems from Greek mythology. Is there a problem with wearing their apparel with this symbol? Additionally since it Asur to learn Greek mythology (see [Shulhan Aruch Orah Haim 307:16](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40431&st=&pgnum=437)) maybe this symbol is Asur.

Comment: I assumed this was about tzniut.

Comment: Where in 307? That's about Shabbath, not about 'Avodah Zarah.

Comment: @SethJ 15 or 16 can't remember.

Comment: @HachamGabriel, that's still about Shabbath, with the exception of part of 16, which states that it is Moshav Leitzim to read those things generally. It has nothing to do with 'Avodah Zarah. (I'd be sympathetic to an objection to _any_ graven image, with a good argument, but this doesn't support the premise of your question.)

Comment: @SethJ in 16 he says that fairytales and novels are Asur Mishum Al Tifnu El HaElilim if I remember correctly.

Comment: @HachamGabriel, you are correct. He does say "Asur Mishum Moshav Leitzim _Ve'Over Mishum Al Tifnu El HaElilim_." But the next bit confuses me; is he limiting the previous Psak? Can anyone else chime in who can see it right now? I'll add the HebrewBooks.org link above in the question.

Comment: @SethJ כז מליצות ומשלים של דברי חולין והבל, או ספר שיש בו דברי חשק [רומן] ומלחמות, אסור לקרות בהם בשבת. ואף בחול אסור לקוראם, ועובר  משום אל תפנו אל האלילים, לא תפנו אל מדעתכם from Yalkut Yosef seems like everything is under Al Tifnu.

Comment: However, I still have to ask: if you're not reading the material, how would you know the image in the brand is related? Furthermore, you still haven't established that wearing an image (on a fashion label) related to a fairy tale is Asur. Is it Asur to wear a Harry Potter t-shirt?

Comment: @SethJ the last part of your comment is essentially my question.

Comment: Also, simple point of order - shouldn't your title be "Is it Asur", not "Is it Mutar"? Just for consistency's sake?

Comment: What about true religion symbol with buddah on it?

Comment: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=48843&st=&pgnum=490 Harav Michael Peres is oser true religion clothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From this [Igros Moshe YD 1:69](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=917&pgnum=122) which discusses selling stamps with crosses on them ,he says they are mutar because it is for noi(decoration).This is just a source for savorah.

Comment: Can anyone Lomdishly apply this to my case?

Comment: What about the true religion symbol?